# Projectile motion with drag force of the form $\vec f =-k \vec v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile, drag

An object is fired with initial velocity $v_0$ at inclination angle $\theta$ above the horizontal. Drag force in the air is taken into account and is of the form $\vec f =-k \vec v$.

Knowing that the velocities in $x$ and $y$ direction are
$$v_x(t) = v_{x_0} e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$$
and
$$v_y(t)=-\frac{mg}{k} + (v_{y_0} + \frac{mg}{k})e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$$
where 
$v_{x_0}=v_0 \cos \theta $ and $v_{y_0}=v_0\sin \theta$,
I want to find the velocity $v_f$ with which the object ends its motion.
How could it be found?

Comment: Flippantly: the motion ends when the velocity is zero. More helpfully: you need to find out how long the flight lasts - which you can do by integrating the velocity formula to get y position. See how far you get with that and update your question if you are still stuck.

Comment: @Floris: Integrating in the $\hat{y}$ direction to get the position gives $\vec {r}_y=-\frac{mg}{k}t + \frac{m}{k}(v_{y_0} + \frac{mg}{k})(1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}t})$ and $$-\frac{mg}{k}t + \frac{m}{k}(v_{y_0} + \frac{mg}{k})(1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}t})=0$$ is not quite solvable...

Comment: It's tricky, but wolfram alpha says [it's solvable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a*t+%3D+b*%281-e%5E%28c*t%29%29+for+t)

Comment: I am not familiar with the "Lambert W-Function" $W_k(z)$. Are you sure about this reasoning?

Comment: If you assume that $\frac{k}{m}t$ is small, you can expand the expression and it can be solved on paper. That might make more sense - because the W function is a beast and you have a transcendental ($\approx\text{hard}$) equation there.

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question to include the work you have done - this is becoming more interesting.

Comment: I don't have more work to post. That's all I got: The equation for velocity and displacement in each axis.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate $v_y$ over time and solve for when that equals zero. That time is when it hits ground again and will let you find $v_f$